# Move semantics performance test

Tags: c++, sorting, move, semantics, insertion

I wrote this code to test the performance of move constructor, comparing to STL vector. Created 2 classes LargeType uses the vector container from the Standard Template Library (STL). On the other hand, LargeTypeRaw uses a raw pointer.
At the end created two vectors of LargeType and LargeTypeRaw with random numbers Calls a custom insertSort function to sort the two vectors Measures the time it takes to sort the two vectors and prints the results.  Results for 10.000 vectorsize are like:

Sorting LargeType Result: 2.52 sec    --- Sorting LargeTypeRaw Result: 0.28 sec

My question : Is the difference between 2 tests are extremely high? and what might be  the reason regarding the complete code below? Could you please help me figure out?

```
t#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class LargeType {
public:
    explicit LargeType(int initialSize = 10)
        : data(initialSize) {}

    int getSize() const {

        return data.size();
    }
    // Operator '<' LargeType 
    bool operator<(const LargeType& rhs) {
        return data.size() < rhs.data.size();
    }

private:
    vector<T> data;
};

// Assignment Part 2 -3
template <typename T>
class LargeTypeRaw {
public:
    explicit LargeTypeRaw(int size = 10)
        :sizeRaw {size}, dataRaw {new T[sizeRaw] }
        {}

    // LargeTypeRaw Copy constructor
    LargeTypeRaw(const LargeTypeRaw <T>& rhs) 
        //: sizeRaw {rhs.sizeRaw}, dataRaw {new T[sizeRaw] } 
    {
        sizeRaw = rhs.sizeRaw;
        dataRaw = new T[sizeRaw];
        copy(rhs.dataRaw, rhs.dataRaw + sizeRaw, dataRaw);
        //copy(rhs.dataRaw, rhs.dataRaw + sizeRaw,dataRaw);
    }

    // LargeTypeRaw Move constructor
    LargeTypeRaw(LargeTypeRaw&& rhs) noexcept
        : sizeRaw{rhs.sizeRaw} , dataRaw {rhs.dataRaw}
    {
        rhs.dataRaw = nullptr;
        
    }

    // LargeTypeRaw Copy assignment operator '= '
    LargeTypeRaw& operator=(const LargeTypeRaw& rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
                       
            delete[] dataRaw;
            sizeRaw = rhs.sizeRaw;
            dataRaw= new T [sizeRaw];
                      
            copy(rhs.dataRaw, rhs.dataRaw+sizeRaw, dataRaw);
                     
        }
        return *this;

        // LargeTypeRaw Smaller than operator  ' <' 
    }
    bool operator<(LargeTypeRaw & rhs) {
        return  this->sizeRaw < rhs.getSize();
    }
    // LargeTypeRaw Move assignment operator
    LargeTypeRaw& operator=(LargeTypeRaw && rhs) noexcept {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            delete[] dataRaw;
            sizeRaw= rhs.sizeRaw;
            dataRaw = rhs.dataRaw;
            rhs.dataRaw = nullptr;
     
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // LargeTypeRaw  Destructor
    ~LargeTypeRaw() {
        delete[] dataRaw;
    }

    int getSize() const
    {
        return sizeRaw;
    }

private:
    int* dataRaw;
    int sizeRaw;
};

//Insertion sort algorithm with vector
template <typename T>
void insertSort(vector<T> & arr) {

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        auto key = move(arr[i]);
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j > -1 && key < arr[j]) {
            arr[j + 1] = move(arr[j]);
            j--;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = move(key);
    }
}


int main() {

    srand (time(NULL)); 
    // Assignment Part 4- Testing and comparing the Copy and Move Constructor performances 

    int vecSize = 10000;

    // Filling the vector arrays with random numbers 1-100
    vector<LargeType<int>> vecLarge (vecSize);
    vector<LargeTypeRaw <int>> vecRaw (vecSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++) {

        int randNum =rand() % 100;
        vecLarge[i]= LargeType<int> {randNum};
    
        vecRaw[i] = LargeTypeRaw<int> {randNum};
    }

    // Setting the start time
    clock_t start1 = clock();

    //Calling the sorting function and printing out the elapsed execution time 
    insertSort(vecLarge);
    cout << "Sorting LargeType Result: " << (clock() - start1) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC )  << endl;

    clock_t start2 = clock(); // Reset the start time for the second sort function call
    insertSort(vecRaw);
    cout << "Sorting LargeTypeRaw Result: " << (clock() - start2) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC ) << endl;
```

the expected result: largetype vector result should be faster than typeraw vector and the anticipated gap might be less?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations on? What compiler are you using?

Comment: Did you compile in debug or release mode, i.e. turn in optimizations?

Comment: This code generates quite a few warnings and a crash for me because of variables being initialized incorrectly. https://godbolt.org/z/sW517v68K

Comment: This warning suggests the presence of a critical bug:  `./test.cpp:31:41: warning: field 'sizeRaw' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]  :sizeRaw {size}, dataRaw {new T[sizeRaw] }` <-- you are allocating an array of a random number (uninitialized value!) of T's in your constructor!

Comment: the code is running without any exception or error at my end. Using Visual Code and GCC compiler on linux

Comment: I will check that Jeremy Friesner! Thanks for commenting

Comment: I have corrected the warning issue by initializing the array with a constant value rather than using the T value.  Retired Ninja thanks! when I analyse the the code on C++ insights, I debug the warnings one y one since i get the result 0. Now i got Sorting LargeType Result: 2.63s
Sorting LargeTypeRaw Result: 1.38s . the gap is narrowing but still is that normal or not?

Comment: The correct thing to do is swap the order of `dataRaw` and `sizeRaw` in the class definition. Variables are initialized in the order they are declared, not the order they appear in the constructor initialization list.